# How to use devise to give privilege to different user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am a teacher(admin) that create 3 different questions(posts) to 3 students(users). Each student can and only can view the post with their name on it.

How can I do it?

Comment: [Privileges/Authorization](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos#privilegesauthorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a filed that is called `is_teacher?` or something like that

so now you can do

in your post controller

```
def index 
  if current_user.is_teacher?
    @post = Post.all
  else
    @post = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

I hope that this is able to help.